# Looking to interact with a DbContext entity through a different service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 2 Data Models let's call them Lecture/Teacher that have a one-to-many relationship, in a service method I need to get a `teacherId` given a certain condition and add it to the Lecture model instance.
Below is the definition of the different Models.

```
namespace Example.Core.Data;

public class Lecture
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public string TeacherId { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int duration { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class LectureInput
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string TeacherField { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Duration { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Teacher Model:

```
public partial class Teacher
    {
        public Teacher()
        {
            Lectures = new HashSet<Lecture>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; } = null!;
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Field { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Department { get; set; } = null!;
        [JsonIgnore] public virtual ICollection<Lecture> Lectures { get; set; }
    }
```

As I have access to the `DbContext` in the `LectureService` at first I thought I could use it to directly get the `teacherId`, like so:

```
using Example.Core.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class LectureService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public LectureService(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int Create(LectureInfo input)
    {
      var lecture = new Lecture
        {
            Name = input.Name,
            teacherId = _context.Teachers //here
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(t => t.Field == input.TeacherField)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Name)
                .FirstOrDefault().Id,
            duration = input.Duration
        }
      _context.Lectures.Add(lecture);
      _context.SaveChanges();

      return lecture.Id;
}
```

But later I figured we do need to use that same logic in another place and had to add it to the `TeacherService`, so I thought if it was okay to use dependency injection and call the method from the `TeacherService` inside `LectureService`, like this:

```
using Example.Core.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class TeacherService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public TeacherService(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    public int GetTeacherIdByField(string field)
    {
        return context.Teachers
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(t => t.Field == field)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Name)
                .FirstOrDefault().Id
    }
}
```

And then just call the method in the LectureService, like this:

```
using ContractManager.Core.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
public class LectureService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly TeacherService _teacherService;

    public LectureService(DbContext context, TeacherService teacherService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _teacherService = teacherService;
    }

    public int Create(LectureInfo input)
    {
      var lecture = new Lecture
        {
            Name = input.Name,
            teacherId = teacherService.GetTeacherIdByField(input.TeacherField),
            duration = input.Duration
        }
      _context.Lectures.Add(lecture);
      _context.SaveChanges();

      return lecture.Id;
}
```

Is it viable to use the second option or should I stick to using the `DbContext` directly in the `LectureService` ?

Comment: Code Review is somewhat [different](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) from Stack Overflow. You might also want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @pacmaninbw can you point out what needs improving? I tried to follow the guide and be as clear and concise as I can.

Comment: We like to see as much code as possible so that we do good reviews. We need to see the full classes as well as the using statements at the top of the C# file. We don't answer specific questions.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why do you use the sync API of EF instead of the async one?

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answer makes sense again.

Comment: @TobySpeight ah okay my bad, I'll try adding it in an answer then, thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there only one teacher per field? What is they type of value found in `input.field`? I think "philosophy", "math", "Computer Science", etc. - I was thinking the same as with BCDotWeb answer below - what stops you from transmitting an id when you submit data for creating a lecture?

Comment: @topsail this was just an example and not the actual query I am using, and I was wondering if querying an Entity from another Model Service using DbContext is fine or if I should inject that Entity's Service into the other one and use the corresponding method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick remarks:

- What does "Field" on "Teacher" represent? Moreover, why wouldn't you get the teacher's ID from the user input? Presumably the user selects from a list, what is stopping you from presenting them with a list of names which translates to an ID when transmitting to the API?
- `.FirstOrDefault().Id` will break when the result is NULL. If you think the result can be NULL, then you must anticipate this. If the result cannot be NULL, then there's no point in using "OrDefault".
- Also, why `.FirstOrDefault()`? If you expect multiple results to be possible, why would the first one be the correct one?
- Why is `TeacherId` a string when `Id` is an int on `Teacher`?
- Why is `duration` lowercase?
- `public int Age { get; set; }` Are you going to update this field once a year?
- `public string Department { get; set; }` This should be an ID linking to a separate table, since I presume a department can have multiple teachers. See [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).
- If you're calling a method inside the `TeacherService`, there's no need to use the words "Teacher" in the method name (IMHO), e.g. `GetTeacherIdByField`.

---

Now, when it comes to your question of using one service inside another: I wouldn't do it like that. I'd instead opt to have a separate class, e.g. `TeacherRetriever`, which contains the logic inside `GetTeacherIdByField` and then use this retriever in both services.

Comment: Thank you for your kind remarks, I tried fixing some of the things you pointed out. As I pointed out at the start this is an analogy to what I am working with so I didn't put too much thought in the fields (last 2 remarks). As for the first one I meant by Field their Speciality or Module, as for the interaction with the API it's a bit more complicated so that's not an option for the moment. Thanks again for your input, I am somewhat new to asp.net so I didn't pay attention to the `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: "this is an analogy to what I am working with" Please note this makes your question off-topic. We require ***concrete code***, otherwise a review is pointless. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and advice, I'll try reading the new links you provided, and respecting it in the future if I need more reviews.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the answer by @BCdotWEB, I fixed the problems in my code and here's a new version with the suggested changes:

- Changed the `TeacherId` field in `Lecture` Model from `string` to `int`.
- Changed the `Duration` field to uppercase.
- Used `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault` as I am not expecting the value to be `null`.

Below is the definition of the different Models.

```
namespace Example.Core.Data;

public class Lecture
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public int TeacherId { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class LectureInput
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string TeacherField { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Duration { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Teacher Model:

```
public partial class Teacher
    {
        public Teacher()
        {
            Lectures = new HashSet<Lecture>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; } = null!;
        public int Age { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Field { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Department { get; set; } = null!;
        [JsonIgnore] public virtual ICollection<Lecture> Lectures { get; set; }
    }
```

#### First approach:

```
using Example.Core.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class LectureService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public LectureService(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int Create(LectureInfo input)
    {
      var lecture = new Lecture
        {
            Name = input.Name,
            TeacherId = _context.Teachers //here
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(t => t.Field == input.TeacherField)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Name)
                .First().Id,
            Duration = input.Duration
        }
      _context.Lectures.Add(lecture);
      _context.SaveChanges();

      return lecture.Id;
}
```

#### Second approach:

```
using Example.Core.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class TeacherService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public TeacherService(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    public int GetTeacherIdByField(string field)
    {
        return context.Teachers
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(t => t.Field == field)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Name)
                .First().Id
    }
}
```

And then just call the method in the `LectureService`, like this:

```
using ContractManager.Core.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
public class LectureService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly TeacherService _teacherService;

    public LectureService(DbContext context, TeacherService teacherService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _teacherService = teacherService;
    }

    public int Create(LectureInfo input)
    {
      var lecture = new Lecture
        {
            Name = input.Name,
            TeacherId = teacherService.GetTeacherIdByField(input.TeacherField),
            Duration = input.Duration
        }
      _context.Lectures.Add(lecture);
      _context.SaveChanges();

      return lecture.Id;
}
```

Is it viable to use the second option or should I stick to using the `DbContext` directly in the `LectureService` ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While OPs are [encouraged to answer their own questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) bear in mind that ["_Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)... Perhaps making a follow-up question with a link back to this question would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I just thought it would be better to update the code on the same question rather than making a new question and correcting the few things that @BCdotWEB pointed out, as my original question still has no answer. Should I make a new question from the current answer then, in that case wouldn't it be a duplicate for this one? Or would I need to rewrite the whole thing and ask the question differently?

Comment: FYI I have updated my answer with a reply to your question of whether to use one service inside another.